# Значения или для js где найти эти две полосы?

Tags: javascript

```
if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
```

Comment: В смысле, где они на клавиатуре? Это два одинаковых символа подряд, ищите на клавиатуре одну ровную вертикальную полосу,  обычно под Backspase вместе со слешами.

Comment: спасибо, нашел наконец)